# I want to have a user select a number that they want to keep and put in an array. And have them put into separate index's

Tags: c++

I so far have that the user is asked what dice they want held and I put those into an array. But when I put it in the array I want those numbers to stay. But for the next turn I want to be able to add to the array with other numbers without it changing the others.

```
cin >> Hold;
            switch (Hold)
            {
            case 1: DieHolder[0] = die1;
                cout << "If you are done choosing dice use the 0 key to end." << endl;
                break;
            case 2: DieHolder[1] = die2;
                cout << "If you are done choosing dice use the 0 key to end." << endl;
                break;
            case 3: DieHolder[2] = die3;
                cout << "If you are done choosing dice use the 0 key to end." << endl;
                break;
            case 4: DieHolder[3] = die4;
                cout << "If you are done choosing dice use the 0 key to end." << endl;
                break;
            case 5: DieHolder[4] = die5;
                cout << "If you are done choosing dice use the 0 key to end." << endl;
                break;
            }
```

I have it so the numbers are put in a specific spot but can't seem to be able to add from the next turn without it changing the previous numbers.

Then I have it displayed to the screen.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            if (DieHolder[i] >= 1)
            {
                cout << i << ": " << DieHolder[i] << "\n";
            }
        }
```

I'm unsure on how to save the old numbers.

Comment: One solution I've seen is rather than storing only the number in the array, you store a structure that aggregates the number along with a flag that tells the program whether the number is to be kept or not. When rolling, test the flag. If it is set, don't generate a new number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are facing is mainly within the for loop and the switch statement.
Each time you run it you overwrite the element that was on that same index.

There are a a number of ways you could do this, but I would suggest using a vector instead because it will allocate memory for you. With a regular c-style array (as you are using) that keeps growing you would have to resize the reserved memory yourself for it to be able to grow safely.

This would be a safer approach and also more dynamic solution to your problem.

1. Create a `std::vector< std::vector<> >` type to have it represtented in 2 dimensions.
   (Imagine it as a grid, where along Y are the users choice of rows. And along X are the dies placed there)

- Not recommended to use 'using std;' due to potential
  conflicts of definition, but for learning purposes it is fine. and will make for cleaner code due to not having to write `std::` before `vector`

  ```
    /* ... Outside Loop Body ... */  
    using std; 

    // This will initialize 5 rows of vectors, which will be where choices stack   
    vector<vector<int>> DieHolder(5, vector<int>{});
  ```

Inside the loop body:

1. My assumption is that the switch is to place die1, die2 etc in certain 'rows'
2. Using `at()` as below is to access a certain row.
3. With a given row accessed, use `emplace_back()` to construct a new element on the end-column belonging to that row.

   ```
    /* ... Loop Body ... */ 

    cin >> Hold;
    switch (Hold)
    {
        // emplace_back() Will NOT overwrite, it will stack choices.
        case 1: DieHolder.at(0).emplace_back(die1);
        break;
        case 2: DieHolder.at(1).emplace_back(die2);
        break;
        case 3: DieHolder.at(2).emplace_back(die3);
        break;
        case 4: DieHolder.at(3).emplace_back(die4);
        break;
        case 5: DieHolder.at(4).emplace_back(die5);
        break;
    }
    cout << "If you are done choosing dice use the 0 key to end." << endl;

    /* ... */
   ```

Then using a nested range based loop you can print out each elements content as such

```
    /* ... */
    for (auto & elements_row : DieHolder ){
        for(auto & elements_column : elements_row){
            cout << "Row: " << elements_row << endl;
            if (elements_column >= 1){
                cout << "Column: " << elements_column << endl;
            }
        }
    }
    /* ... */
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using 2 dimensional arrays.  For example, say `die1` is defined as:

```cpp
int *die1;
int d1loc = 0;
```

`die1` is an `int * (int pointer)`, so it points to the location of an `int`.  `d1loc` signifies which `int (dice number)` `die1` is on.

Here's your program rewritten to use 2 dimensional arrays.

```cpp
int *die1, die2, die3, die4, die5;
int dloc[5] = {0};
cin >> Hold;
switch (Hold)
{
  case 1: DieHolder[0][dloc[0]++] = die1;
    cout << "If you are done choosing dice use the 0 key to end." << endl;
    break;
  case 2: DieHolder[1][dloc[1]++] = die2;
    cout << "If you are done choosing dice use the 0 key to end." << endl;
    break;
  case 3: DieHolder[2][dloc[2]++] = die3;
    cout << "If you are done choosing dice use the 0 key to end." << endl;
    break;
  case 4: DieHolder[3][dloc[3]++] = die4;
    cout << "If you are done choosing dice use the 0 key to end." << endl;
    break;
  case 5: DieHolder[4][dloc[4]++] = die5;
    cout << "If you are done choosing dice use the 0 key to end." << endl;
    break;
}
for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
  for (int j = 0; j < dloc[i][j]; j++)
    cout << i << ": " << DieHolder[i][j] << "\n";
```

Try this yourself and if it doesn't work, tell me in the comments

Comment: My dice are made with a rand I don't know how I can do that with int *die1, die2, die3, die4, die5;    I'm still very new to c++

Comment: @Gamez : To insert a random number at a new location do: `DieHolder[DICE_NUMBER][dloc[DICE_NUMBER++]] = RANDOM_NUMBER` You should generate the random number and put it in this format to insert it in the next position.